# What is a good workflow between blender and 3d coat?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I bought 3d coat pro. I upgraded from an old edu license I bought three years ago and now I'm trying to find a good workflow between blender and 3d coat. I mostly make game models like characters, weapons, props and modular level assets. I also do a bunch of animation. My old workflow consisted of building a hp mesh and baking it to a low poly mesh with cage mesh via xnormal. Sometimes I cheat and do a lp mesh and beef up the poly count for baking then paint heightmaps (saves a ton of time for simple stuff). From there I generate my own textures in blender and gimp then use substance painter indie to put together my textures for pbr usage. But now that I have 3d coat I have some new options for my asset creation process. Not sure which route to take. Lots of possibly. What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I also use 3D Coat, the built in AddOn helps a lot. You have to go into preferences and enable it.
My workflow is: Sculpt Highpoly in 3DCoat, retopo and lowpoly in 3DCoat, Exporting Highpoly and transfering the lowpoly to Blender for unwraping, after that just baking in xNormal.